# Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 + Wayland: extreme CPU usage

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, wayland, cpu-load

Fresh installed Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop + Wayland. Whole desktop laggy af. Mouse movement like 3 fps and when typing something, it needs 1 second to display the characters on the console.

- `htop` output **without** moving mouse:

[image: without moving mouse]

- `htop` output **with** moving mouse:

[image: with moving mouse]

There are no extensions installed.

Comment: Do you still have the issue if you use Xorg? And can you [edit] your question to directly add in it more info about your system's specifications, because the link you provided does not longer work?